# QItemDelegate with custom view widget

Tags: qt, qt5, model-view, qitemdelegate

Qt 5.5 has a virtual method to define a custom widget for editing mode:

```cpp
QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent,const QStyleOptionViewItem & option ,const QModelIndex & index ) const
```

But how to use a custom widget to override the "view" mode?
I saw "stars rating" delegate example where `paint` method is used but that's not what I need. I need to show a custom widget that contains other standard widgets inside it and use it in a view mode of `QTableView` or `QListView`. No need to get mess with painting pointers and figures - just show a custom widget (that has .ui file) and contains other standard widgets with their behaviour.

For example:
There is a download manager application that can show downloads either as a table or list view. `QListView` with a list of downloads. Each download has URL, Title, TotalSize, DownloadedSize, ProgressBar, Pause button, Remove button, Resume button. All of those can be columns in a table (`QTableView`) or composed similar to HTML's DIV in one cell (`QListView` widget)

How to achieve it? Is there anything like `QWidget *createViewer(...` ?

QtWidgets are used no QML.

Comment: Why it should be a widget in viewing mode?

Comment: @vahancho very common example - QListView with a list of downloads. Each download has URL, Title, TotalSize, DownloadedSize, ProgressBar, Pause button, Remove button, Resume button. All of those can be columns in a table (QTableView) or composed similar to HTML's DIV in one cell (QListView widget)

Comment: You might try to use `QListWidget` and `QListWidget::openPersistentEditor()` function to show the editor in viewing mode.

Answer (score 1):

For static content you can use `QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget`.

For dynamic content the only option is to implement `paint` method in you delegate class.